# Php can not load module phalcon

Tags: php, ubuntu, phalcon

I successfuly installed phalcon 4.0 framework. Also I check phpinfo() on browser and there is phalcon, but if check php modules, there is not the palcon. 
Also if I check php module by this command,

```
php -m | grep phalcon
```

I get this php warning:

```
Cannot load module 'phalcon' because required module 'psr' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried add extension=psr.so to php.ini, but it still not worling.

I also create 50-phalcon.ini file on  /etc/php/7.3/apach2/conf.d folder, still not working.

Please help me, I have no idea how to solve this problem. Please help!

Answer (score 5):

You have installed v4 which requires the PSR extension to be loaded first.

Have a look at this article: https://docs.phalconphp.com/4.0/en/upgrade

In short `psr.so` has to be present in your system and loaded before Phalon.

Comment: Yes, I tried this. I installed  PSR extension and it compiled successfuly. Also I add 

extension=psr.so  

before the 

extension=phalcon.so

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

```
#Ubuntu

$ zephir -V
PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'phalcon' because required module 'psr' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
Zephir 0.12.12 by Andres Gutierrez and Serghei Iakovlev (1094502)

php -v
PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'phalcon' because required module 'psr' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.24-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019 18:29:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

PS: I extended psr.so and configured it to php.ini
But it doesn't compile when running zephir

Comment: Hello JasonMetal. I have 'corrected' your answer so that your 2 images are directly visible on StackOverflow answer. To do that, you must only make a paste/copy of images. It is a good practice on StackOverflow to put image directly on post.